# Override rails activerecord touch method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

Is there a way to override rails default method which touches the timestamps of related models?

Example:

```
class User
  belongs_to :employer, touch: true
end
```

I want to override the touch method which instead of touching the timestamp of employer should  do something else.

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to do something like this

```
class User
  ...
  def touch

    # your fancy stuff goes here

    super
  end
end
```